# TCL: can a procedure run inside another procedure and share all vars between them without upvar?

Tags: tcl, procedure

lets say I want:

```
proc set_valid {} {
    set valid 1
    puts "$printme"
}

proc valid_start {} {
    set valid 0
    set printme "ABC"
    valid_stop
    return valid
}
```

that `valid_start` will return 1, Can I use it some how without `upvar`? that all variables will be shared between the procs?

I just want to have the following instead,

```
proc valid_start {} {
    set valid 0
    set printme "ABC"
    ####
    set valid 1
    puts "$printme"
    ####
    return valid
}
```

Just to be able to repeat some lines of code just like "source" do to a .tcl file but to a specific code block in the same .tcl , Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud try to play with the command info and eval to realize what you're trying to do. But in a software engineering view I would not recommand doing that, you're kind of beating the purpose of a function

```
proc proc1 {} {
    set valid 1
}

proc proc2 {} {
    set valid 0
    set code [info body proc1]
    eval $code
    puts $valid
}

proc2
```

Answer (score 3):

Every procedure has its own local variables; to refer to the local variables of a caller procedure you *must* use `upvar` (or `uplevel` to run a command to manipulate them in the right scope).

```
proc set_valid {{printme "the message"}} {
    upvar 1 valid valid
    set valid 1
    puts "$printme"
}
```

The `global` and `variable` commands are very similar, but are (typically) used to refer to global variables and current-namespace variables respectively instead.

With that procedure definition, you can then do:

```
proc valid_start {} {
    set valid 0
    set printme "ABC"
    # Stuff...

    set_valid $printme

    # I guess you want to return the variable contents, not the name?
    return $valid
}
```

You could also transfer the `printme` variable by the same mechanism (see below), but I recommend keeping the number of “magically available” variables to a minimum; it's much clearer and more maintainable if variables are sent by value, sent by explicitly-passed name, or declared at the top with `global` or `variable` (where appropriate).

```
proc set_valid {} {
    # Emphasising that local variable names are different to the caller's names
    upvar 1 valid abc printme def
    set abc 1
    puts "$def"
}
proc valid_start {} {
    set valid 0
    set printme "ABC"
    # Stuff...
    set_valid
    return $valid
}
```

---

If you're wanting your procedure to work like something `source`d right there, use `uplevel 1`.

```
proc set_valid {} {
    uplevel 1 {
        set valid 1
        puts "$printme"
    }
}
```

That's how you do macro-like things. If you need to do code generation in this, the `list` command is extremely useful. Ask another independent question here on Stack Overflow if you want to learn more.